# Using leaflet or google map to create layer of multiple attributes

Tags: leaflet, google-maps, layers, filter

I am creating a map with leaflet layer. Right now, each marker has three different attributes and I would like to create layers base on these three attributes (Model, group, and status). I am able to show only all the models, only all the groups, or only all of the status.

THE NEED : I was wondering if anyone knows how to create layer that can do AND filter? So I can filter something like show all the Model A in group 2 and status is active? Or show all the model B and status are active?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would probably be to implement the AND filter yourself using JavaScript.

Probably something in the lines of:

```js
function applyAndFilter(val1, val2, val3) {
  layerGroupOnMap.clearLayers();

  layerGroupReference.eachLayer(function (layer) {
    if (layer.prop1 === val1 && layer.prop2 === val2 && layer.prop3 === val3) {
      layerGroupOnMap.addLayer(layer);
    }
  });
}
```

`layerGroupReference` would hold all of your layers / markers, but it should not be on map.

`layerGroupOnMap` would be the container group that will receive the filtered layers / markers. It should be on map, even if empty.

Then you would trigger the `applyAndFilter` after map initialization, and whenever your selection changes for any of the 3 attributes.